# Как правильно оформить запрос "Form Data"?

Tags: python, requests

На панели для разработчиков, запрос выглядит так: (Google Chrome)

**Form Data**

```
country_detect: 1
item[]: 176.101.89.226
item[]: 33470
key: *************************
```

В ответе json, сайт почему-то указывает на ошибку:

`{'error': ['Proxy format error']}`

Сам запрос оформляю так:

```
form_data = {
        "country_detect": "1",
        "item[]": "176.101.89.226",
        "item[]": "33470",
        "key": "******************"
    }
response = self.post(self.urls[2], data=form_data, timeout=60)
```

Comment: 1. Почему в имени ключа присутствуют запрещённые символы скобок?
2. Повторяющиеся ключи также запрещены

Comment: Хорошо, вы мне дали пищу для размышлений :-) Но я как-бы задал недвусмысленный вопрос.

Comment: Ну, так мой ответ предполагал, что это может и быть причиной ошибки)